# Accessing cookies from React SSR

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

Here is the simple thing.
React routing redirect path depends on the value in cookies, so how do I handle it Server Side?

```
render() {
  something = cookie.get('my-something-value') || 'default '; // always takes defualt value beacuse cookies are not available 
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route />
      <Route />
      <Redirect to={`/something/${val}`}/>
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

So `renderToString` method in the server parses elements to string ignoring this condition and I get wrong redirect even though I have cookies set

Comment: What's your setup? This is specific to how you do SSR. If you were using Next, you could possibly make use of some third-party addons that address that. Otherwise you will need to link `cookies with server cookies somehow.

Comment: I use [universal-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie) on my project for this, works well

Answer (score 2):

I had faced similar kind of issue. It was resolved by:

- Pass an extra prop (here: serverCookie) containing cookie to your routes in renderToString.
- In the render method (where you have defined all routes/redirect); check if it is getting called on client or server. If it is on server-side, use the new prop (here: serverCookie) containing cookie otherwise use the cookie.get from client-side.
- The extra prop (here: serverCookie) is not available when routes are rendered in client-side.

My renderToString on server side looked somewhat like this:

```
renderToString(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <StaticRouter ...>
      <MyRoutes ... serverCookie={req.headers.cookie} />
    </StaticRouter>
  </Provider>
)
```

MyRoutes file looked like:

```
render(){
  const cookie = isServerSide
    ? this.props.serverCookie
    : cookie.get('my-something-value')
  const path = cookie ? "/pathC" : "/pathD"
  return (
    <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/pathA"
          component={ComponentA}
        />
        <Route
          path="/pathB"
          component={ComponentA}
        />
        <Redirect to={path} />
      ...
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

Note: You will need to parse your cookies properly using some cookie-parser before using.

Hope it helps and solves your issue. Revert for any doubts/clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

use cookie parser middleware

`npm i cookie-parser`

**Example**

```
var express = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // Cookies that have not been signed
  console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies)

  // Cookies that have been signed
  console.log('Signed Cookies: ', req.signedCookies)
})

app.listen(8080)
```